# How to create the tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> with XMLOption (XMLBeans)?

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

How can i create the header of a XML Document, which was created by using XML Beans and XMLOptions?

I have developed this kind of java code to the right encoding and deleted unnecessary namespaces:

```
final Map<String, String> implicitNamespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
implicitNamespaces.put("", "http://www.test.com/results");
XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
xmlOptions.setSaveImplicitNamespaces(implicitNamespaces);
xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
xmlOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();
```

But how can i create the header  by using XMLBeans and XMLOptions? Is it the only way to set it hard coded? If there is´t a method to create this tag?

Answer (score 0):

The `<?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“ISO-8859-1”?>` construct is an *[**XML declaration**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl)*.

Per [org.apache.xmlbeans.save(ContentHandler ch, LexicalHandler lh)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28org.xml.sax.ContentHandler,%20org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler%29):

> Writes the XML represented by this source to the given SAX content and
>   lexical handlers. Note that this method does not save the XML
>   declaration, including the encoding information. **To save the XML
>   declaration with the XML, see [save(OutputStream)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream%29), [save(OutputStream,
>   XmlOptions)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.OutputStream,%20org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions%29), [save(File)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.File%29) or [save(File, XmlOptions)](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlTokenSource.html#save%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions%29)**.